# Antd form remote submit

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to trigger the submit button outside the antd form

Here is my code

```
<Form
          {...layout}
          name="basic"
          initialValues={{
            remember: true,
          }}
          onFinish={onFinish}
          onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        >

     <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your username!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    
    <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
           // Submit button here works well
          </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

I want this outside form tag, please suggest

```
 <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
     Submit
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try this way:

```js
 const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const handleFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("values: ", values);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <MyForm form={form} onFinish={handleFinish} />
      <Button onClick={() => form.submit()}>Submit</Button>
    </div>
  );
```

```js
export const MyForm = ({ form, onFinish }) => {
  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      initialValues={{ username: "John Doe" }}
    >
      <Form.Item name="username">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit strange-currying-ttkv1]

Answer (score 4):

If the form and the button are not in the same component then it is hard to create same reference for the form in 2 different place. But I found an other easy way:

```
<Form id="myForm">...</>
...
<Button form="myForm" key="submit" htmlType="submit">
  Submit
</Button>
```

This is the answer from [this issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/9380)

Comment: this works only for an uncontrolled form, the answer above is the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

write a custom function like this:

```js
function handleSubmit(){
  form.validateFields().then((values) => {
    // do something with values
  })
}
```

and call it from Button onClick. so you don't need Form `onFinish` props.

Comment: how can I create reference for the  form

Comment: in antd v4 use this: `const [form] = Form.useForm();`

Answer (score 0):

sorry i was searching and see this old question.

as in the comment you should use
`const [form] = Form.useForm();`

that's a lot of function you can use one of them is `submit`.

`form.submit();`

you can refer to document and search for useform:

https://ant.design/components/form/